# WebSockets: How to notify all subscribers when a client connection has dropped?

Tags: ruby, websocket, eventmachine, em-websocket

I have a little WebSocket chat demo that I am working on ([based on this code](https://gist.github.com/1308112/be4bbaf4bd7b74fe116f7264552fbe71844dbb48)). However, the part that doesn't seem to be working is when a connection is closed between a client and the server, I want to notify all the subscribers that the user has "left the chatroom". I thought that the server would be notified/run the onclose function when the client connection was dropped, but maybe that's not how WebSockets work.

Here's my EventMachine code:

```
  ws.onclose do
    puts "Connection closed"
    ws.send ({:type => 'status', :message => "#{@subscribers[subscriber_id]} has left the chatroom"}.to_json)
    @main_channel.unsubscribe(subscriber_id)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send data to a WebSocket that was just closed, that won't work. You probably want to just push a message to the Queue like:

```
ws.onclose do
  puts "Connection closed"
  msg = {:type => 'status', :message => "#{@subscribers[subscriber_id]} has left the chatroom"}.to_json
  @main_channel.push(msg)
  @main_channel.unsubscribe(subscriber_id)
end
```

That way the message will be send to all subscribers.

Best regards

Tobias